# Swift 2.2 - Disallow app from accessing System accounts

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, twitter-fabric

I need a big help. I am using TwitterKit to login a twitter account. But I don't want my existing twitter account to be accessed. In short, I want to show the login view every time I click the login button.

I tried many things including logging out the session on TwitterKit.

Please help me. I want my app to be not allowed accessing the system accounts (Programmatically not via settings). Thanks!

Comment: Why? most users will enjoy not having to type in their credentials again and simply using the one they've already logged into. Why do you want to circumvent that?

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin Because I want to login multiple accounts.

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin Any idea??

Comment: ... so have a sign out button? and sign back in. If there is an account on the phone, the list of accounts is displayed. If there are no accounts, you are presented with a login.

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin did that already mate.. it will still access the accounts on the device. I need to sign in many accounts.

Comment: you did what? did you even read my comment?

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin the thing is i know this : ... so have a sign out button? and sign back in. If there is an account on the phone, the list of accounts is displayed. If there are no accounts, you are presented with a login. ..... I want to restrict my app from accessing my accounts.

Comment: We are going back around in circles. I have actually read your question, you've already stated that. I don't think that is possible, unless you want to implement all of the twitterKit functionality yourself using the API. I'm asking, why someone would want to even try this. What reason do you need to restrict access to your accounts, why is accessing your accounts an issue? Why would users of your app want this functionality? what benefit does this give them? Your not explaining what you ultimately want to achieve

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin HootSuite (ios app) is doing it mate.. If i have 1 account on my phone and i want to add another one. the app will present a login view instead.